# Dropdown Resetting When Changing Option - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns that are related to each other. The HTML for these are below:

```
<div class=form-group>
    <label for="ab_provider">
        <?php _e( 'Teacher', 'management' ) ?>
    </label>
    <select id="ab_provider" class="field form-control" ng-model="form.staff" ng-options="s.full_name for s in dataSource.data.staff" ng-change="onStaffChange()"></select>
</div>
<div class=form-group>
    <label for="ab_service">
        <?php _e( 'Class Type', 'management' ) ?>
    </label>
    <select id="ab_service" class="field form-control" ng-model="form.service" ng-options="s.title for s in form.staff.services" ng-change="onServiceChange()">
        <option value="">
            <?php _e( '-- Select a class type --', 'bookly' ) ?>
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is my JS which sets up the form both when adding and editing.

```
module.factory('dataSource', function($q, $rootScope, $filter) {
    var ds = {
        loaded : false,
        data : {
            staff         : [],
            customers     : [],
            start_time    : [],
            end_time      : [],
            time_interval : 900,
            status        : {
                items: [],
                default: null
            }
        },
        form : {
            screen     : null,
            id         : null,
            staff      : null,
            service    : null,
            date       : null,
            repeat     : {
                enabled  : null,
                repeat   : null,
                daily    : { every : null },
                weekly   : { on : null },
                biweekly : { on : null },
                monthly  : { on : null, day : null, weekday : null },
                until    : null
            },
            schedule   : {
                items : [],
                edit  : null,
                page  : null,
                another_time : []
            },
            start_time : null,
            end_time   : null,
            customers  : [],
            notification : null,
            series_id  : null
        },
        loadData : function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (!ds.loaded) {
                jQuery.get(
                    ajaxurl,
                    { action : 'bookly_get_data_for_appointment_form' },
                    function(data) {
                        ds.loaded = true;
                        ds.data = data;
                        // Add empty element to beginning of array for single-select customer form
                        ds.data.customers.unshift({name: ''});

                        if (data.staff.length) {
                            ds.form.staff = data.staff[0];
                        }
                        ds.form.start_time = data.start_time[0];
                        ds.form.end_time   = data.end_time[1];
                        deferred.resolve();
                    },
                    'json'
                );
            } else {
                deferred.resolve();
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        findStaff : function(id) {
            var result = null;
            jQuery.each(ds.data.staff, function(key, item) {
                if (item.id == id) {
                    result = item;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return result;
        },
        findService : function(staff_id, id) {
            var result = null,
                staff  = ds.findStaff(staff_id);

            if (staff !== null) {
                jQuery.each(staff.services, function(key, item) {
                    if (item.id == id) {
                        result = item;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
            return result;
        },
        findTime : function(source, date) {
            var result = null,
                value_to_find = $filter('date')(date, 'HH:mm'),
                time = source == 'start' ? ds.data.start_time : ds.data.end_time;

            jQuery.each(time, function(key, item) {
                if (item.value >= value_to_find) {
                    result = item;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return result;
        },
        findCustomer : function(id) {
            var result = null;
            jQuery.each(ds.data.customers, function(key, item) {
                if (item.id == id) {
                    result = item;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return result;
        },
        resetCustomers : function() {
            ds.data.customers.forEach(function(customer) {
                customer.custom_fields     = [];
                customer.extras            = [];
                customer.status            = ds.data.status.default;
                customer.number_of_persons = 1;
                customer.compound_token    = null;
                customer.location_id       = null;
                customer.payment_id        = null;
                customer.payment_type      = null;
                customer.payment_title     = null;
            });
        },
        getDataForEndTime : function() {
            var result = [];
            if (ds.form.start_time) {
                var start_time = ds.form.start_time.value.split(':'),
                    end = (24 + parseInt(start_time[0])) + ':' + start_time[1];
                jQuery.each(ds.data.end_time, function(key, item) {
                    if (item.value > end) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (item.value > ds.form.start_time.value) {
                        result.push(item);
                    }
                });
            }
            return result;
        },
        setEndTimeBasedOnService : function() {
            var i = jQuery.inArray(ds.form.start_time, ds.data.start_time),
                d = ds.form.service ? ds.form.service.duration : ds.data.time_interval;
            if (ds.form.service && ds.form.service.duration < 86400) {
                if (i !== -1) {
                    for (; i < ds.data.end_time.length; ++i) {
                        d -= ds.data.time_interval;
                        if (d < 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    ds.form.end_time = ds.data.end_time[i];
                }
            }
        },
        getStartAndEndDates : function() {
            var start_date = moment(ds.form.date.getTime()),
                end_date   = moment(ds.form.date.getTime()),
                start_time = [0,0],
                end_time   = [0,0]
                ;
            if (ds.form.service && ds.form.service.duration >= 86400) {
                end_date.add(ds.form.service.duration, 'seconds');
            } else {
                start_time = ds.form.start_time.value.split(':');
                end_time   = ds.form.end_time.value.split(':');
            }
            start_date.hours(start_time[0]);
            start_date.minutes(start_time[1]);
            end_date.hours(end_time[0]);
            end_date.minutes(end_time[1]);

            return {
                start_date : start_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:00'),
                end_date   : end_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:00')
            };
        },
        getTotalNumberOfPersons : function () {
            var result = 0;
            ds.form.customers.forEach(function (item) {
                result += parseInt(item.number_of_persons);
            });

            return result;
        },
        getTotalNumberOfNotCancelledPersons: function () {
            var result = 0;
            ds.form.customers.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.status != 'cancelled' && item.status != 'rejected') {
                    result += parseInt(item.number_of_persons);
                }
            });

            return result;
        },
        getTotalNumberOfCancelledPersons: function () {
            var result = 0;
            ds.form.customers.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.status == 'cancelled' || item.status == 'rejected') {
                    result += parseInt(item.number_of_persons);
                }
            });

            return result;
        }
    };

    return ds;
});

/**
 * Controller for 'create/edit appointment' dialog form.
 */
module.controller('appointmentDialogCtrl', function($scope, $element, dataSource, $filter) {
    // Set up initial data.
    $scope.$calendar = null;
    // Set up data source.
    $scope.dataSource = dataSource;
    $scope.form = dataSource.form;  // shortcut
    // Error messages.
    $scope.errors = {};
    // Callback to be called after editing appointment.
    var callback = null;

    /**
     * Prepare the form for new event.
     *
     * @param int staff_id
     * @param moment start_date
     * @param function _callback
     */
    $scope.configureNewForm = function(staff_id, start_date, _callback) {
        var weekday = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'][start_date.format('d')];
        jQuery.extend($scope.form, {
            screen     : 'main',
            id         : null,
            staff      : dataSource.findStaff(staff_id),
            service    : null,
            date       : start_date.clone().local().toDate(),
            start_time : dataSource.findTime('start', start_date.format('HH:mm')),
            end_time   : null,
            repeat     : {
                enabled  : 0,
                repeat   : 'daily',
                daily    : { every: 1 },
                weekly   : { on : [weekday] },
                biweekly : { on : [weekday] },
                monthly  : { on : 'day', day : start_date.format('D'), weekday : weekday },
                until    : start_date.clone().add(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            },
            schedule   : {
                items : [],
                edit  : 0,
                page  : 0,
                another_time : []
            },
            customers  : [],
            notification  : 'no',
            internal_note : null,
            venue : null,
            term : null,
            inset_days : null,
            min_cost_per_class : null,
            min_no_pupils_per_class : null,
            cost_per_pupil : null,
            max_number_in_class : null,
            teachers_fee : null,
            class_created_by : null
        });
        $scope.errors = {};
        dataSource.setEndTimeBasedOnService();
        callback = _callback;

        $scope.reInitChosen();
        $scope.prepareExtras();
        $scope.prepareCustomFields();
        $scope.dataSource.resetCustomers();
    };

    /**
     * Prepare the form for editing an event.
     */
    $scope.configureEditForm = function(appointment_id, _callback) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        jQuery.post(
            ajaxurl,
            {action: 'bookly_get_data_for_appointment', id: appointment_id},
            function(response) {
                $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        var start_date = moment(response.data.start_date),
                            end_date   = moment(response.data.end_date);
                        jQuery.extend($scope.form, {
                            screen     : 'main',
                            id         : appointment_id,
                            staff      : $scope.dataSource.findStaff(response.data.staff_id),
                            service    : $scope.dataSource.findService(response.data.staff_id, response.data.service_id),
                            date       : start_date.clone().local().toDate(),
                            start_time : $scope.dataSource.findTime('start', start_date.format('HH:mm')),
                            end_time   : start_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == end_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                                ? $scope.dataSource.findTime('end', end_date.format('HH:mm'))
                                : $scope.dataSource.findTime('end', (24 + end_date.hour()) + end_date.format(':mm')),
                            repeat     : {
                                enabled  : 0,
                                repeat   : 'daily',
                                daily    : { every: 1 },
                                weekly   : { on : [] },
                                biweekly : { on : [] },
                                monthly  : { on : 'day', day : '1', weekday : 'mon' },
                                until    : start_date.clone().add(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                            },
                            schedule   : {
                                items : [],
                                edit  : 0,
                                page  : 0,
                                another_time : []
                            },
                            customers  : [],
                            notification : 'no',
                            internal_note : response.data.internal_note,
                            venue : response.data.venue,
                            term : response.data.term,
                            inset_days : response.data.inset_days,
                            min_cost_per_class : response.data.min_cost_per_class,
                            min_no_pupils_per_class : response.data.min_no_pupils_per_class,
                            cost_per_pupil : response.data.cost_per_pupil,
                            max_number_in_class : response.data.max_number_in_class,
                            teachers_fee : response.data.teachers_fee,
                            class_created_by : response.data.class_created_by,
                            series_id  : response.data.series_id
                        });

                        $scope.reInitChosen();
                        $scope.prepareExtras();
                        $scope.prepareCustomFields();
                        $scope.dataSource.resetCustomers();

                        var customers_ids = [];
                        response.data.customers.forEach(function (item, i, arr) {
                            var customer = $scope.dataSource.findCustomer(item.id),
                                clone = {};
                            if (customers_ids.indexOf(item.id) === -1) {
                                customers_ids.push(item.id);
                                clone = customer;
                            } else {
                                // For Error: ngRepeat:dupes & chosen directive
                                angular.copy(customer, clone);
                            }
                            clone.ca_id             = item.ca_id;
                            clone.extras            = item.extras;
                            clone.status            = item.status;
                            clone.custom_fields     = item.custom_fields;
                            clone.number_of_persons = item.number_of_persons;
                            clone.location_id       = item.location_id;
                            clone.payment_id        = item.payment_id;
                            clone.payment_type      = item.payment_type;
                            clone.payment_title     = item.payment_title;
                            clone.compound_token    = item.compound_token;
                            clone.compound_service  = item.compound_service;
                            $scope.form.customers.push(clone);
                        });
                    }
                    $scope.loading = false;
                });
            },
            'json'
        );
        $scope.errors = {};
        callback = _callback;
    };

    var checkTimeInterval = function() {
        var dates = $scope.dataSource.getStartAndEndDates();
        jQuery.post(
            ajaxurl,
            {
                action         : 'bookly_check_appointment_date_selection',
                start_date     : dates.start_date,
                end_date       : dates.end_date,
                appointment_id : $scope.form.id,
                staff_id       : $scope.form.staff ? $scope.form.staff.id : null,
                service_id     : $scope.form.service ? $scope.form.service.id : null
            },
            function (response) {
                $scope.$apply(function ($scope) {
                    $scope.errors = response;
                });
            },
            'json'
        );
    };

    $scope.onServiceChange = function() {
        $scope.dataSource.setEndTimeBasedOnService();
        $scope.reInitChosen();
        $scope.prepareExtras();
        $scope.prepareCustomFields();
        checkTimeInterval();
    };

    $scope.onStaffChange = function() {
        $scope.form.service = null;
    };

    $scope.onStartTimeChange = function() {
        $scope.dataSource.setEndTimeBasedOnService();
        checkTimeInterval();
    };

    $scope.onEndTimeChange = function() {
        checkTimeInterval();
    };

    $scope.onDateChange = function() {
        checkTimeInterval();
    };

    $scope.processForm = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;

        var dates     = $scope.dataSource.getStartAndEndDates(),
            schedule  = [],
            customers = []
        ;

        angular.forEach($scope.form.schedule.items, function (item) {
            if (!item.deleted) {
                schedule.push(item.slots);
            }
        });

        $scope.form.customers.forEach(function (item, i, arr) {
            var customer_extras = {};
            if ($scope.form.service) {
                jQuery('#bookly-extras .service_' + $scope.form.service.id + ' input.extras-count').each(function () {
                    var extra_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
                    if (item.extras[extra_id] !== undefined) {
                        customer_extras[extra_id] = item.extras[extra_id];
                    }
                });
            }
            customers.push({
                id                : item.id,
                ca_id             : item.ca_id,
                custom_fields     : item.custom_fields,
                extras            : customer_extras,
                location_id       : item.location_id,
                number_of_persons : item.number_of_persons,
                status            : item.status
            });
        });

        jQuery.post(
            ajaxurl,
            {
                action        : 'bookly_save_appointment_form',
                id            : $scope.form.id,
                staff_id      : $scope.form.staff ? $scope.form.staff.id : null,
                service_id    : $scope.form.service ? $scope.form.service.id : null,
                start_date    : dates.start_date,
                end_date      : dates.end_date,
                repeat        : JSON.stringify($scope.form.repeat),
                schedule      : schedule,
                customers     : JSON.stringify(customers),
                notification  : $scope.form.notification,
                internal_note : $scope.form.internal_note,
                venue : $scope.form.venue,
                term : $scope.form.term,
                inset_days : $scope.form.inset_days,
                min_cost_per_class : $scope.form.min_cost_per_class,
                min_no_pupils_per_class : $scope.form.min_no_pupils_per_class,
                cost_per_pupil : $scope.form.cost_per_pupil,
                max_number_in_class : $scope.form.max_number_in_class,
                teachers_fee : $scope.form.teachers_fee,
                class_created_by : $scope.form.class_created_by
            },
            function (response) {
                $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        if (callback) {
                            // Call callback.
                            callback(response.data);
                        }
                        // Close the dialog.
                        $element.children().modal('hide');
                    } else {
                        $scope.errors = response.errors;
                    }
                    $scope.loading = false;
                });
            },
            'json'
        );
    };

    // On 'Cancel' button click.
    $scope.closeDialog = function () {
        // Close the dialog.
        $element.children().modal('hide');
    };

    $scope.reInitChosen = function () {
        jQuery('#bookly-chosen')
            .chosen('destroy')
            .chosen({
                search_contains     : true,
                width               : '100%',
                max_selected_options: dataSource.form.service ? dataSource.form.service.capacity + dataSource.getTotalNumberOfCancelledPersons() : 0
            });
    };

    $scope.statusToString = function (status) {
        return dataSource.data.status.items[status];
    };
```

The options for both dropdowns are from two different tables that have a relationship with each and the services that are listed as options in the second drop down are reloaded based on the staff member chosen in the first dropdown. However, the services in the second dropdown will also reset even if the staff member chosen in the first dropdown can offer the same service. Is there a way I can change the behaviour of the second drop-down-menu to not reset unless it actually has to?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking, and what did you try so far to achieve that?

Comment: I have updated the code to include the JS. However, in terms of what I am doing I'll give an example.

Currently if I wanted to change the staff member (using the first dropdown), then the second dropdown will reset and load the services he can offer. This drop down will reset even if the staff member is changed to another who can offer the same service. This is the part that I want to fix.

Comment: Please add a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar.